# Check if file exists in current directory

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I'm using this piece of C code in Linux to check if file exists in the same directory as the ".c" file:

```
int file_exist(char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

but it always returns false even though the file exists! Is the problem that Linux is searching in a different directory? How to solve this?

Comment: It looks for a file in your current dir, not in C-source dir. Besides closing the file would be nice.

Comment: `fopen()` can return a `NULL` pointer even if the file exists.

Comment: Not to mention that file could be there, but you don't have permission to open it for reading. Why don't you just call `access(filename, F_OK)`?

Comment: What is current directory?

Comment: The directory, from which you start the program. http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd

Comment: access is always returning True !

Comment: Don't forget to close the file if you successfully open it.  Note that `fopen("xyz.txt", "r");` opens the file for reading in the current directory of the process, which is typically not the same as the directory where the source code for the program is stored, unless you happen to run it from a shell which has the source directory as its current directory.

Comment: Try passing an absolute path to `file_exist()`. Also be aware the the backslash in DOS pathes needs be "escaped" (prefixed by a backslash) in C like `file_exist("C:\\autoexec.bat")` to address a file.

Answer (score 2):

Just use stat - http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat

If it returns 0 then the file exists. You can even find out if you can read it.

Comment: Just a small note, if `stat()` returns `-1` you can check `errno == ENOENT` to make sure the file doesn't exist and it didn't fail for another reason.

Answer (score -2):

Use ferror method to test everything is okay with input file.

```
 FILE *fp;
 fp = fopen("RECORD.txt","r");

 if (ferror(fp) != 0){
  printf("File has error");
  exit(0);
 }
```

Comment: This is really bad idea. If the file fails to open, `fp` is `NULL`, and `ferror` may crash.